# ASP.NET Core RC-1 file upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am currently uploading a file via the kendo fileuploader to an api controller using ASP.NET core RC-1. I am receiving a periodic error of "object reference not set to instance of object" when attempting to read the stream following opening the stream with IFormFile.OpenReadStream().

My controller is:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/{domain}/[controller]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromRoute]string domain, [FromForm]IFormFile file, [FromForm]WebDocument document)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var userName =
                        Request.HttpContext.User.Claims
                            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypesEx.FullName)?
                            .Value;

                    var uploadedFileName =
                        ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                    document.Domain = domain;
                    document.MimeType = file.ContentType;
                    document.SizeInBytes = file.Length;
                    document.ChangedBy = userName;
                    document.FileName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.FileName)) ? uploadedFileName : document.FileName;

                    try
                    {
                        document = await CommandStack.For<WebDocument>()
                            .AddOrUpdateAsync(document, file.OpenReadStream()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
                    }

                    return Ok(document);
                }
            }
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }
```

And the error is being thrown when I actually try to read the stream when it is going into blob storage:

```
public async Task<Uri> CreateOrUpdateBlobAsync(string containerName, string fileName, string mimeType,
        Stream fileStream)
    {
        var container = Client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        //Error HERE
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);

        blob.Properties.ContentType = mimeType;
        await blob.SetPropertiesAsync();
        return blob.Uri;
    }
```

What I am having trouble with is this is sporadic and there seems to be no defined pattern of which files are accepted and which ones generate the error. At first I thought it might be a size issue but that is not the case as I have several larger files uploaded successfully and then one small file will throw the error. Images seem to work fine and it is hit or miss on other file types with no rhyme or reason that I can figure out.

Comment: If you think this is a problem with ASP.NET move to RC2 - a lot of things changed and was fixed between RC1 and RC2 so there is no point in beating a dead horse.

Comment: How do I add RC2, I can't seem to find it on Nuget?

Comment: Here is a RC1 to RC2 migration guide: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html

Comment: Thanks, that will definitely come in handy. When I convert I will circle back and update this thread.